# HTTP: If document is cached, then how come I cannot access it through session history?

Tags: javascript, http, caching

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching):

> Cache is used to make visited documents available for back/forward
> navigation, saving, viewing-as-source, etc. without requiring an
> additional trip to the server. It likewise improves offline browsing
> of cached content.

I have noticed an irregular behavior in Google Chrome however, where I am often (but not always) unable to access pages via browser's back button, if I have gone offline.

That is odd, as browsers should by default cache all documents they encounter, as seen in [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-2):

> Although caching is an entirely OPTIONAL feature of HTTP, it can be
> assumed that reusing a cached response is desirable and that such
> reuse is the default behavior when no requirement or local
> configuration prevents it.

Anyone know why this irregular behavior occurs, and how long the default expiry time is for the browser's private cache?

---

### EDIT

I am aware of the below section from [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2), but it does not answer the question unfortunately. The text is still vague:

> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
> a cache MAY assign a heuristic expiration time when an explicit time
> is not specified, employing algorithms that use other header field
> values (such as the Last-Modified time)... If the response has a
> Last-Modified header field (Section 2.2 of [RFC7232]), caches are
> encouraged to use a heuristic expiration value that is no more than
> some fraction of the interval since that time. A typical setting of
> this fraction might be 10%.

Do typical web page responses have a `Last Modified` header field by default, by the way?